# Expose temp tables to SSRS in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, ssrs

Problem: Compare data of a given date range to the same data of up to 3 previous years, and display the tabular data and a graph in an SSRS report. However currently, my stored procedure that I have made for the SSRS report doesn’t work, as it uses temp tables, which aren’t exposed to SSRS. I totally get why, SSRS has no clue about the structures on the temp tables I’ve created.

For example, I want to see the count widgets made from 01/01/2012 to 04/01/2012, grouped by hour.

So the logical layout of the table is:

```
 Hour Count
    0   100
    1   240
    2   34
    3   24
    4   55
    5   90
    …
    23  7657
```

So for that data, I want to compare it to how the plant did the previous year(s) (up to 3), for the same date range. 
It seems so simple, yet the solution that I came up with, is anything but.

I’ve worked it out so that, I have a table-valued function that calculates the required data for the given start_date and end_dates, and pulls the data from the source table. I believe that is the right way to do it?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Count_TS] (@SDate DATETIME2,@EDate DATETIME2)
    RETURNS @t TABLE ([Hour] INT,[Count] INT) AS
    BEGIN
     INSERT @t ([Hour],[Count])
            SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,AC.[FIELDC]) AS [Hour],COUNT(DISTINCT(AC.[FIELDD])) AS [CFS_Count_1]
            FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] AS AC WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE (AC.[FIELDA] LIKE 'VALUE' OR AC.[FIELDA] LIKE 'VALUE')  
            AND AC.[FIELDB] = 'VALUE'
            AND (CAST(AC.[FIELDC] AS DATE) >= @SDate AND CAST(AC.[FIELDC] AS DATE) <= @EDate)
            GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,AC.[FIELDC])

    RETURN
    END
```

The bit where it goes downhill is the manner in which I have constructed the stored procedure to display the data in the SSRS report. The stored proc doesn’t need explaining, it’s fairly evident of what I have done. Which it cannot be the “right” way to do this?

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [rptCount_TS] 
      @PREYears INT = NULL
     ,@SDate DATE = NULL
     ,@EDate DATE = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF DATEDIFF(MONTH,@SDate,@EDate) <=3 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,@SDate,@EDate) =0
    BEGIN

    IF @PREYears = 0
        BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CountPrime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#CountPrime]; 
            CREATE TABLE #CountPrime ([Hour] INT,[CountPrime] INT)
            INSERT INTO #CountPrime([Hour], [CountPrime]) 
                SELECT [Hour],[Count] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (@SDate,@EDate)
            SELECT  CCP.[Hour]
                        ,CCP.[CountPrime]
            FROM    #CountPrime AS CCP
        END
    ELSE
        IF @PREYears =1
            BEGIN
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CountPrime1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#CountPrime1]; 
                CREATE TABLE #CountPrime1 ([Hour] INT,[CountPrime] INT)
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-11') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-11]; 
                CREATE TABLE [#Count-11] ([Hour] INT,[Count-1] INT)
                INSERT INTO #CountPrime1([Hour], [CountPrime]) 
                                SELECT [Hour],[Count] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (@SDate,@EDate)
                INSERT INTO [#Count-11]([Hour], [Count-1]) 
                    SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-1] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate));
                SELECT  CCP.[Hour]
                        ,CCP.[CountPrime]
                        ,SC1.[Count-1]
                FROM    #CountPrime1    AS CCP
                INNER JOIN [#Count-11] AS SC1 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC1.[Hour]
            END
        ELSE
            IF @PREYears =2
                BEGIN
                    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CountPrime2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#CountPrime2]; 
                    CREATE TABLE #CountPrime2 ([Hour] INT,[CountPrime] INT)
                    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-12') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-12]; 
                    CREATE TABLE [#Count-12] ([Hour] INT,[Count-1] INT)
                    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-22') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-22]; 
                    CREATE TABLE [#Count-22] ([Hour] INT,[Count-2] INT)     
                    INSERT INTO #CountPrime2([Hour], [CountPrime]) SELECT [Hour],[Count] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (@SDate,@EDate)
                    INSERT INTO [#Count-12]([Hour], [Count-1]) 
                        SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-1] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate));
                    INSERT INTO [#Count-22]([Hour], [Count-2]) 
                        SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-2] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-2,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-2,@EDate));
                    SELECT  CCP.[Hour]
                            ,CCP.[CountPrime]
                            ,SC1.[Count-1]
                            ,SC2.[Count-2]
                    FROM    #CountPrime2    AS CCP
                    INNER JOIN [#Count-12] AS SC1 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC1.[Hour]
                    INNER JOIN [#Count-22] AS SC2 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC2.[Hour]
                END
            ELSE
                IF @PREYears =3
                    BEGIN
                        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CountPrime3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#CountPrime3]; 
                        CREATE TABLE #CountPrime3 ([Hour] INT,[CountPrime] INT)
                        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-13') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-13]; 
                        CREATE TABLE [#Count-13] ([Hour] INT,[Count-1] INT)
                        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-23') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-23]; 
                        CREATE TABLE [#Count-23] ([Hour] INT,[Count-2] INT)
                        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Count-33') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[#Count-33]; 
                        CREATE TABLE [#Count-33] ([Hour] INT,[Count-3] INT)
                        INSERT INTO #CountPrime3([Hour], [CountPrime]) SELECT [Hour],[Count] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (@SDate,@EDate)
                        INSERT INTO [#Count-13]([Hour], [Count-1]) 
                            SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-1] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate));
                        INSERT INTO [#Count-23]([Hour], [Count-2]) 
                            SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-2] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-2,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-2,@EDate));
                        INSERT INTO [#Count-33]([Hour], [Count-3]) 
                            SELECT [Hour],[Count] AS [Count-3] FROM [Connector].dbo.[Count_TS] (DATEADD(YEAR,-3,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-3,@EDate));
                            SELECT  CCP.[Hour]
                                    ,CCP.[CountPrime]
                                    ,SC1.[Count-1]
                                    ,SC2.[Count-2]
                                    ,SC3.[Count-3]
                            FROM    #CountPrime3    AS CCP
                            INNER JOIN [#Count-13] AS SC1 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC1.[Hour]
                            INNER JOIN [#Count-23] AS SC2 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC2.[Hour]
                            INNER JOIN [#Count-33] AS SC3 ON CCP.[Hour] = SC3.[Hour]
                    END
    END
    ELSE
    PRINT 'Sorry, at maximum you can only search a 3 month time span.'
```

If this is the way to do the project, how can I expose the tables inside of the stored proc to SSRS? Do I have to fumble my way through converting it to another TVF? I looked up SET’ing FMTONLY, and sp_describe_first_result_set, but those did not seem like viable solutions. [Should I roll up all guts of the stored proc into the first TVF?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/22/stored-procedures-with-ssrs-hmm-not-so-much.aspx),can I keep the stored proc and use CTEs in place of temp tables?

Is this what SSAS is for?

Comment: The problem is not that "temp tables aren’t exposed to SSRS", the problem lies in that your sp gives a result set with different number of columns depending on your parameters. That's not allowed in SSRS. You should always return the same number of columns for your dataset

Comment: I've changed my stored proc to select the same number of columns across each IF statement. Still doesn't work. any other pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to skin the cat, without learning and using SSAS (which doesn't mean I won't).

I have 4 datasets in my report, one houses the hour count and CountPrime, the others house Prime -1, Prime-2, Prime-3. 
I am using the function from the very top of my post;

```
SELECT *
FROM [Count_TS](DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@SDate),DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate))
```

I am just using DATEADD() to do the work of getting me the previous 3 months. 
As I am sure you'll notice, I am not doing logic of grabbing only the previous years that the user asks for, I am always giving the previous 3 years.

Once in SSRS, I am using the LOOKUP() function to grab the results from the other datasets and aggregate them into one table/graph.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Hour.Value,Fields!Hour.value,Fields!Count.value,"Minus1")
```

After I got the LOOKUP() function working in SSRS, it was clear sailing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get what you want by doing the following:

(1) combine function and procedure into 1 select statement
(2) add grouping by Year to single SELECT
(3) I added recursive CTE to generate "HOUR" dimension and use this instead of getting hour from actual data; this will show hours with 0 then

```
WITH HourOfDay ([hr]) AS  
(  
  SELECT 1 as [hr]  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT [hr] + 1  
  FROM HourOfDay  
  WHERE [hr] < =24       
) 
SELECT   
    DATEPART(YEAR,AC.[FIELDC]) AS [Year]  
    --DATEPART(HOUR,AC.[FIELDC]) AS [Hour],   
    hod.hr AS [Hour],  
    COUNT(DISTINCT(AC.[FIELDD])) AS [CFS_Count_1]  
FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] AS AC WITH (NOLOCK)  
JOIN HourOfDay AS hod  
    ON hod.[hr] = DATEPART(HOUR,AC.[FIELDC])  
WHERE (AC.[FIELDA] LIKE 'VALUE' OR AC.[FIELDA] LIKE 'VALUE')    
AND AC.[FIELDB] = 'VALUE'  
AND (CAST(AC.[FIELDC] AS DATE) >= @SDate AND CAST(AC.[FIELDC] AS DATE) <= @EDate)  
GROUP BY   
    DATEPART(YEAR,AC.[FIELDC]),  
    DATEPART(HOUR,AC.[FIELDC])
```

(4) You can add/use SSRS parameter for number of years, pass that to procedure, but also possibly use it to hide columns for years not desired to show on report.